# Values of k for which there exist two distinct real eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$\begin{pmatrix}2&k\\ \:1&5\end{pmatrix}$

So the question is the title itself.

So I found the characteristic polynomial to be:

$x^2-7x+10-k$

After factoring it became:

$\left(x-2\right)\left(x-5\right)-k$

So if we ignore the k the eigenvalues would be 2 and 5. But I am not sure how I would treat the problem with k present.

Any help?

Comment: See whether the discriminant is positive?

Comment: Right. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Write
$$
x^2 - 7x - k + 10 = \left( x-\frac{7}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{49}{4}-k+10
$$
Now, we see that
$$
x^2 - 7x - k + 10 = 0 \iff x = \pm\sqrt{10 -k-\frac{49}{4}} +\frac{7}{2}
$$
So, there exists two distinct real eigenvalues if and only if 
$$
10 -k-\frac{49}{4}>0 \iff k<10-\frac{49}{4} = -\frac{9}{4}
$$

Comment: What if we take $k=10$? In that case we have exactly two linearly independent eigenvectors...

Comment: @MostafaAyaz But the eigenvalues won't be real

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem implying that if are eigenvalues of a matrix are distinct then the eigenvectors are all linearly independent. Here the characteristic equation is $x^2-7x+10-k=0$. If the discriminant is zero therefore $$49=4(10-k)$$ or $$k=-\dfrac{9}{4}$$therefore if $k\ne-\dfrac{9}{4}$ we attain what we want also the discriminant should be non negative therefore the answer is$$k\lt-\dfrac{9}{4}$$